# Trying to set the size/location of a button in a tab for SWT

Tags: swt

This should be pretty simple but this is the first time I've worked with SWT. This is what I have so far.

```java
public class TabsTest {

private Shell shell;
private CTabFolder folder;

public TabsTest(Display display){

    shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("TabsTest");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    CTabFolder folder = new CTabFolder(shell, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.BOTTOM);
    folder.setUnselectedCloseVisible(false);
    folder.setSimple(false);

    initUI(folder);

    shell.pack();
    shell.setBounds(500, 500, 400, 500);
    shell.open ();

    while(!shell.isDisposed()){
        if(!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }   
}

public void initUI(CTabFolder folder){
    CTabItem NFL = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
    NFL.setText("NFL Bets");

    Button okButton = new Button(folder, SWT.PUSH);
    okButton.setText("OK");
    okButton.setSize(10,10);

    NFL.setControl(okButton);

    CTabItem NBA = new CTabItem(folder,SWT.NONE);
    NBA.setText("NBA Bets");

    CTabItem CFB = new CTabItem(folder,SWT.NONE);
    CFB.setText("CFB Bets");        

    folder.setSize(800,500);

}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    new TabsTest(display);
    display.dispose();
}
```

}

What this currently gives me is this....

[image: picture]

How would I make this a small button in the bottom right corner? Or just in general make it smaller and move it somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a `FillLayout` the control takes up the entire space available. What you need is a different kind of a layout. I will suggest you to read [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html), it will be a good start.

I generally prefer `GridLayout` as it is quite easy to use and it fulfills most needs.

**Edited**: Modifying your code to use `GridLayout`

```java
public class TabsTest {

    private Shell shell;
    private CTabFolder folder;

    public TabsTest(Display display) {
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("TabsTest");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        CTabFolder folder = new CTabFolder(shell, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.BOTTOM);
        folder.setUnselectedCloseVisible(false);
        folder.setSimple(false);
        folder.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));

        initUI(folder);

        shell.pack();
        shell.setBounds(500, 500, 400, 500);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }

    public void initUI(CTabFolder folder) {
        CTabItem NFL = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        NFL.setText("NFL Bets");

        Composite nflParent = new Composite(folder, SWT.NONE);
        nflParent.setBackground(folder.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
        nflParent.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        Button okButton = new Button(nflParent, SWT.PUSH);
        okButton.setText("OK");

        GridData gd = new GridData();
        gd.verticalAlignment = GridData.END;
        gd.horizontalAlignment = GridData.END;
        gd.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        gd.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        okButton.setLayoutData(gd);

        NFL.setControl(nflParent);

        CTabItem NBA = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        NBA.setText("NBA Bets");

        CTabItem CFB = new CTabItem(folder, SWT.NONE);
        CFB.setText("CFB Bets");

        folder.setSize(800, 500);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        new TabsTest(display);
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with your code changed to using a GridLayout. But it is better that you read a little on this so that you understand how achieved the desired layout.